# Second argument of gtk_source_mark_attributes_render_icon

Tags: c, gtk, gtksourceview

What should be the second argument of the function `gtk_source_mark_attributes_render_icon()`
It is clearly of type `GtkWidget*` and according to [the reference page](https://developer.gnome.org/gtksourceview/stable/GtkSourceMarkAttributes.html#gtk-source-mark-attributes-render-icon) this is

> "widget of which style settings may be used"

I find it for a bit unclear.

When I call `gtk_source_mark_attributes_render_icon(att, some_random_widget, 40);` Nothing seems to happen and the pixbuf rendered in the gutter is
as small as 10x10 or something. I even set the gutter size to 40, because I initially thought, the image is so small, because the width of the gutter is that small.

How can I render bigger pixbufs in the gutter?

Answer (score 1):

I agree, the documentation is quite unclear on this point. I think the widget should probably be the GtkSourceView corresponding to the buffer.

The size is probably affected by the preceding call to `gtk_source_view_mark_attributes_set_icon_name()` or whatever you are using to tell it which pixbuf to render.

Comment: Made the same guess and tried with the sourceview of the buffer the first time. Also I use `gtk_source_mark_attributes_set_pixbuf`. The pixbuf itself is bigger, the renderer size is big enough to hold it, and `gtk_source_mark_attributes_render_icon` is called. But no effect on the size of the rendered pixbuf.

Comment: Probably the size setting works only on icons in which case I am out of ideas how to  size up the pixbuf in the gutter.

Comment: I've been having the same problem.

Comment: See gtksourcepixbufhelper.c the function `from_pixbuf` it indeed scales the pixbuf "smaller". It is called by `gtk_source_pixbuf_helper_render()` and then the draw signal handler in gtksourcegutterrendererpixbuf.c, which uses `gdk_cairo_surface_create_from_pixbuf()` with the scale parameter.

Comment: If I am to use custom gutter and renderer probably it will behave the same way.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that play a role into how the pixbuf is rendered.
First is the size of the gutter (which is always in width) and second is the height of the line.

According to [gtksourcepixbufhelper.c](https://github.com/GNOME/gtksourceview/blob/master/gtksourceview/gtksourcepixbufhelper.c) the pixbuf is scaled with one unit for both dimensions. As seen in the function `gutter_renderer_pixbuf_draw`, [here](https://github.com/GNOME/gtksourceview/blob/master/gtksourceview/gtksourcegutterrendererpixbuf.c) this unit essentially is `cell_area->width`. This is determined by the size of the gutter.

But the gutter line marks themselves are not coded to be expandable in height, nor they can expand the line in height, so when the gutter is rendered they are clipped.

---

Therefore in order to allow pixbufs to span further one must increase the height of the line. This can happen with the `font-size` property of the GtkTextView.
But the bigger font is usually unwanted too, so to hack this behavior there is one thing that came across my mind.

A secondary overlay text view can be used to display text (should not have gutter) while the bottom text view displays bigger pixbufs. The overlay text view may need left padding with the size of the gutter. And to synchronize pixbufs with lines one will have to use the `pixels-above-lines` and `pixels-below-lines` (tag or textview props) to pad the lines. The height of the line of the bottom text view minus the height of the overlay text view / 2 for both props or something like that.

---

The less hackish solution is to subclass on the gutter (and perhaps the cell renderer) and override the rendering function to implement your own rules.